# RESTful HTTP API design pattern for specifying file pairs?

Tags: rest, api, curl, restful-architecture

I am attempting to design an HTTP API whereby callers would upload N pairs of files per call. I will utilize a toy example to guide the discussion.

Imagine I'm collecting a database of photos that have been doctored. For each record uploaded, I need two files: (1) the original photo, and (2) the doctored photo. I would like users to upload records in batches.  For this example, let's assume the user will upload two records.

I have considered two options:

1. Nested forms: `curl -F "record=@orig0.jpg,doc0.jpg" -F "record=@orig1.jpg,doc1.jpg"`

   This results in top-level form parts containing records, where each record contains to sub-form parts which are the photo files.

   Pros: Logically accurate. Can be done with curl.

   Cons: Sub-form parts don't have field names. Difficult to do through other clients.
2. Form parts with dynamic field names:

   `curl -F "record0_original=@orig0.jpg" -F "record0_doctored=@doc0.jpg" -F "record01_original=@orig1.jpg" -F "record1_doctored=@doc1.jpg"`

   Pros: All field labels are present and expressive.

   Cons: Uses dynamic field names to impart structure.

Is there another option? Is there an established design pattern for specifying multiple binary files and relationships between them?

Comment: When it comes to dynamically generated field names remember that you still need to parse it on the backend side what may also be problematic. I'd rather go for the first solution, maybe because I work with spring and it would be quite easy to do as far as I know. Also, I don't know about any established pattern.